# Public Instagram endpoint without credentials

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am looking for another way to get Instagram media from public accounts. I don't want to provide any credentials. I know that it is possible with the access token from Instagram Basic API, but it is short-lived. Is there any official public endpoint available? I found a `?__a=1`, but it is deprecated. Also, there is a `https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=HASH&variables={"id":"ID","first":COUNT}`, but it isn't mentioned in any official documentation.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean deprecated? Use such a link https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1 and get all the data in json format, then process it how you need.

Comment: On the "Stack Overflow" I found a lot questions that? __ a = 1 is not working anymore. I have checked it and it is working for me actually, but only for the first dozen. It is not acceptable for me, cause I need to have the first 20 images from the Instagram public account.
Now I'm using a graphql endpoint and it is working how I need it.  However, I want to be sure as most as possible that it is the most recommended solution at the moment